# The type or namespace name 'TwilioCapability' could not be found

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to write my first Twilio app. I am following the QuickStart guides but I cannot even build the code in the sample page because it cannot see the TwilioCapability type.

```
@using Twilio;
@{
    string accountSid = "asdfasdfasdf";
    string authToken = "asdfasdfasdfa";

    var capability = TwilioCapability(accountSid, authToken);

    capability.AllowClientOutgoing("APabe7650f654fc34655fc81ae71caa3ff");
    var token = capability.CreateToken();
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013, I have tried various versions of MVC and .Net Framework in case there is a version issue, but it always happens. I can't think of anything else to try...

Hoping someone else has seen this before!

Comment: Did you add the Twilio.Client nuget package?  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio.Client/

Comment: Devin - i hadn't, I have now (note I had to use this specifically Install-Package Twilio.Client -Version 3.5.1) - but amazing, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Seems as though trying the [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio.Client/) - Twilio Client capability token generator for use with the [Twilio Client for browsers JavaScript SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js) did the trick above.

OP Notes use specifically:

```
Install-Package Twilio.Client -Version 3.5.1
```

Comment: I wonder you have solved big problem but no one voted?Thank you very much a vote up from me.